# Why someone serially downvoted most of my posts?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

Today I saw a message "+14 Serial downvoting reversed" in my profile. It seems someone unintentionally downvoted most of my posts in a small span of time but I am not sure why someone did this.
My question is:
**Are my posts of low quality, unclear etc etc..**
I am not specialized in *Physics*. English isn't my first language. I am improving my posts continuously.  If to someone my posts seems unclear he/she should downvote my posts slowly so that next time I won't get my reputation back.

I request the reader to leave some concise comments with constructive criticism on my posts so I could further improve the quality of my posts.
If the reader hasn't spare time to write any comment on individual posts which he/she wants to downvote please leave a small comment here or if the reason is wide then you may put it as an  answer to this question.

If the serial downvoting was due to my some disrespectful comment of mine then I am extremely sorry. 
Now onwards I will not put any vague comment on SE.

Comment: The time interval is over 5 minutes, and it's only a few of your posts, so I don't think that it is serial downvoting (who knows, it may have even been me?). Yes, many of your posts are quite unclear, so I do think you should start to make them less vague.

Answer (score 4):

If someone was serially downvoting your posts, it usually means they were trying to annoy you, not because of anything wrong with your posts. You should ignore this.

Comment: I thought it was SE policy to not attribute intentions to other users, though.

Comment: Well, yes, in the sense that that's part of our expectation of civility. But I'm not attributing intentions to other users. I'm giving information based on past instances of serial downvoting: in the past, when someone serially downvotes, and when the reason for such downvoting has been discerned, it has little or nothing to do with the content of the posts. (If I instead said "Whoever did this is just trying to annoy you," that would be inappropriate.)